# Saving MapCanvas with RubberBand items as image

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, qgsrubberband

I want to save map canvas as image (Project > Import/Export > Export Map to Image...) together with rubber band items(colored areas in the image). But QGIS just saves features of shown layers on map canvas.

[image]

I get the same result when using PyQGIS.

```
iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(filename)
```

How can I save `QgsRubberBand` items by PyQGIS?

Comment: Have you tried to use QGIS 3?

Comment: I think that is not possible

Comment: @ahmadhanb I've tried in QGIS 3. It doesn't save, too.

Answer (score 2):

Saving the map canvas including all `QgsRubberBand` items can be achieved fairly easily using PyQGIS:

```
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
pixmap = canvas.grab(canvas.sceneRect().toRect()) # crop to visible canvas
pixmap.save("path/to/file_name.png", "PNG") # save as image
```

It essentially relies on the [`grab`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#grab) method which can render any widget into a pixmap.

resulting in:

[image: rubberband-export]